# What weapons are there in Paranautical Activity?

Tags: paranautical-activity

So far I have run into M14 (automatic assault rifle), some sort of laser rifle and a chargeable crossbow.

What other weapons are there and how do they behave? How about super weapons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are a list of weapons :

```
Crossbow
Gilead's Gun
Grenade Launcher
M14
Rocket Launcher
Shotgun
Sickle
Trident
```

You can also refer to this table here, found in [Wikia - Paranautical Activity](http://paranautical-activity.wikia.com/wiki/Weapons) for its full behaviour :

[image]